# IPTables not logging packets in Alpine

Tags: iptables, alpine-linux

I have an `Alpine 3.13.5 VM` freshly installed and `iptables v1.8.6 (legacy)` is working properly.

However when I try to log the packets with this command, it's not generating any:

```
iptables -A INPUT -j LOG
```

I have tried changing log levels and creating custom `/etc/syslog.conf`:

```
user.* /var/log/user.log
kern.* /var/log/kern.log
```

`user` logs are redirected to the proper file but there's still no `kern.log`.

Same thing is working out of box on other distros such as Debian.

Comment: Are you sure any packets reach the last rule in the INPUT chain? I suggest you [edit the question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/648241/edit) and add all INPUT chain rules.

Comment: @berndbausch there's no other rule, just a single one to log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BusyBox, which Alpine is based on, seems to only log kernel events when [klogd](https://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html#klogd) is running. Problem is fixed when I run:

```
klogd -c 1
```